# Update DATE of datetime fields

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a few datetime fields.

I create this query for update the date of records.

```
UPDATE $wpdb->posts INNER JOIN $wpdb->arriba ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->arriba.post_id SET $wpdb->posts.post_date = CURDATE(), $wpdb->posts.post_date_gmt = CURDATE(),$wpdb->posts.post_modified = NOW(),$wpdb->posts.post_modified_gmt = CURDATE()
```

The query works fine, but don´t conserve the time of the record and and replaces by 00:00:00

How can I modify ONLY the date and conserve the original time?

Comment: You will need to add the time to it... So like `$wpdb->posts.post_date = CURDATE() + TIME($wpdb->posts.post_date)`

Answer (score 0):

That is a bit tricky.  Probably the simplest way is by adding days.  So, calculate the number of days to add and add that many days:

```
UPDATE $wpdb->posts INNER JOIN
       $wpdb->arriba
       ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->arriba.post_id
    SET $wpdb->posts.post_date = $wpdb->posts.post_date + interval datediff(CURDATE(), $wpdb->posts.post_date) day;
        $wpdb->posts.post_date_gmt = $wpdb->posts.post_date_gmt + interval datediff(CURDATE(), $wpdb->posts.post_date_gmt) day,
        $wpdb->posts.post_modified = NOW(),
        $wpdb->posts.post_modified_gmt = CURDATE();
```